# xcode 6.3 command line update got the git error

Tags: ios, git, xcode6

I just updated my Xcode command line tools version 6.3 but after that I am getting following message for all git command.
like git status
or git rebase ...

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH

Not sure is it command line issue or other issue. Please suggest me. I am blocked now.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In terminal type `which git` just to make sure you have a version installed. If it doesn't give you a path you'll need to install git. I recommend [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) for installing it.

Comment: which git gives me /usr/local/git/bin/git    If I do export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH" it works fine for single terminal session but if I close the terminal, it create same issue again

Comment: after closing terminal If I do which git, it gives me /usr/bin/git

Comment: When you run `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find git` in terminal, do you get `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git`? --  Also to make your PATH works from terminal session to terminal session you need to set your PATH in your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: You need to run the `xcodebuild` command from the directory that contains your project, so it knows which SDK to use. I believe the issue is the project is using an SDK that's not installed on your computer. To see all the SDKs installed use `xcodebuild -sdk -version` in the command line.

Comment: I think my xcode is not working properly from command line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79692/discussion-between-manoj-and-tobias).